# Вывод функций по порядку

Tags: php

Есть функции которые отвечают за вывод определенного контента. Также у них есть свой id, который отвечает за порядок их расположения друг от друга.

```
$hello_id=1;
function Hello()
{ echo 'Привет' }

$name_id=2;
function Name()
{ return 'stackoverflow'; }

$language_id=3;
function Language()
{ return 'на русском'; }
```

Вопрос, как сделать чтобы эти функции можно было выводить по порядку(по возрастанию) . Я как понимаю все это надо делать в цикле но не могу понять как. Спасибо.

Comment: а если выполнить функцию в функции? Или создать еще одну функцию, которая будет вызывать остальные оп порядку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял:

```
$functions = [];

$functions[1] = function() {
    echo "Привет ";
};

$functions[2] = function() {
    echo "stackoverflow ";
};

$functions[3] = function() {
    echo "на русском";
};

// В этом месте их можно отсортировать как угодно, 
// сейчас они отсортированы по возрастанию

foreach($functions as $function) {
    $function();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не думал что в php можно как в js определять функцию через переменную!

Comment: И я бы добавил функцию asort($functions); или arsort

Answer (score 2):

Имя функции - уже ее уникальный `id`

```
function Hello()
{ return 'Привет '; }

function Name()
{ return 'stackoverflow '; }

function Language()
{ return 'на русском'; }

echo Hello() . Name() . Language();
```